# Prism Library in .Net Core 3.1 WPF

Tags: wpf, .net-core, prism

When i select the "Prism Full App (.Net Core)" project template in Visual Studio 2019 and then select Unity as my dependency injection container, the solution created uses the DryIoc dependency injection container instead. This is in .NET Core 3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the template itself looks fine at first glance, it would seem that you have found a bug in the Prism Template Pack. You can report it by opening an issue on GitHub in the Templates Repo https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism.Templates/issues/new/choose

As a work around you can edit the csproj and change Prism.DryIoc to Prism.Unity...

Comment: Thank you for your quick feedback i'll follow your recommendations.